# How to retrieve value from multiple checkboxes Java

Tags: java, swing, action, jcheckbox

I have this SOAP based webservice implemented in Java where the client has a list of checkboxes which after he selects will be stored in the DB.For example for a checkbox of Sex(maschio,femmina) he can select both of them or one of them i implemented it like this but the issue is that the array has fixed size in this case 2 so if the user selects only one of them sexarra[0] will contain it but sexarra[1] will be null so if i pass it to the server it can create problems and the other checkboxes are much larger in size is there any better way to handle this situation? Thank you all in advance your help is really appreciated! i should add that System.out are for testing only:

```
private void femminaActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
    if (femmina.isSelected()) {
        if (sexint == 0) {
            sexint++;
            sexarra[sexint] = femmina.getText();
        } else {
            sexarra[sexint] = femmina.getText();
        }
    }
    System.out.println(sexarra[0]);
    System.out.println(sexarra[1]);
}

private void maschioActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
    if (maschio.isSelected()) {
        if (sexint == 0) {
            sexarra[sexint] = maschio.getText();
            sexint++;
        } else {
            sexarra[sexint] = maschio.getText();
        }
    }
    System.out.println(sexarra[0]);
    System.out.println(sexarra[1]);
}
```

Comment: I edited your code and code tags, please revert if isn't correct

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok i resolved the problem i had, i introduced an integer sexint which gets updated whenever one of the checkboxes is selected thus determining the size of the array here is the code:

```
private void femminaActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                        
    if(femmina.isSelected()){
        if(sexint==0){
          sexint++;
          sexone=femmina.getText();    
        }
        else if(sexint==1){
            sexint++;
        sextwo=femmina.getText();
        }
        else
            sexint--;

    System.out.println(sexint);        
    }
}                                       

private void maschioActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {       
    if(maschio.isSelected()){
        if(sexint==0){
          sexint++;
          sexone=maschio.getText();
        }
        else if(sexint==1){
            sexint++;
        sextwo=maschio.getText();
        }
        else
            sexint--;

    System.out.println(sexint);
    }
}
```

after which i take sexint and use it to instantiate the array sexarra
Thanks everybody for having taken their time in looking at my problem

Answer (score 2):

please read [How to Use Buttons, Check Boxes, and Radio Buttons](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/button.html) and if there are lots of `checkboxes` then you have to read [How to Use the ButtonGroup Component](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/buttongroup.html), something about [Action Listener](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/actionlistener.html), you can find examples [here](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Swing-JFC/CatalogSwing-JFC.htm)

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I have already read about the topics you posted, i can't use buttongroup since it shoudln't be mutual exclusive my issue is the fact that when i get the data from the checkbox and want to store it, i dont exactly know how to handle the array where it is supposed to be stored, since if one element is selected the placeholders for other elements will be empty coz the array has a fixed size.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need any event handler.

If you do need to populate some arrays, only do it when you are submitting your data in the end.  Each button knows its state; there is no need to redundantly store this info in another data structure each time a button is clicked.

In the end, when submitting the finalized data:

```
System.out.println(jButton1.getName() + ": " + jButton1.isSelected());
System.out.println(jButton2.getName() + ": " + jButton2.isSelected());\
...
```

Instead of printing out in your code, you just fill whatever data structure you are sending to the DB when you are ready to submit.

Also you should think about synchronization: you want one method that runs on the Swing EDT to fill your data structure, but some other method on another thread to send those to the DB.  And **somehow** you must make sure the data is synchronized between the two threads.